# List<string> as GridView Datasource. What do I put for DataField in the GV's BoundField?

Tags: .net, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I have a `List<string>` that I'm using as a `DataSource` for a `GridView`. I don't want to auto generate the columns (it gives "Item" as the header). What do I put for the `DataField` to get the string if I'm using a `BoundField`? aka `<%# Eval( [whatgoeshere] ) %>` in the markup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to use TemplateField in that case and not BoundField like:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="My Header">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <%#Container.DataItem %>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

But to your root problem of column header being "Item" you can set your Column Header to your desired value in code-behind with AutoGenerateColumns.
e.g.

```
GridView1.DataSource = list;
GridView1.DataBind();
GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "My Custom Header";
```

Comment: Ah, BoundField won't work in this case. That was the part I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You just need:

```
   <%# GetDataItem().ToString() %>
```

See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.getdataitem.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
<%# Container.DataItem %>
```

to bind the string items to your GridView.