# How can I bind list to gridview?

Tags: c#, json, gridview

I'm trying to take a JSON doc, put that into a list, and bind that to a gridview. I've tried a few different ways, and nothing works. Here is my code and the problem is in the last 4 lines.

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        var from = origin.Text;
        var to = destination.Text;
        var requesturl = @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin =" + from + "&alternatives=false&units=imperial&destination=" + to + "&sensor=false;";
        string content = file_get_contents(requesturl); 


        JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var d = jss.Deserialize<dynamic>(content);
        List<string> sl = d;

        GridView1.DataSource = content;
        GridView1.DataBind();



    }
```

Comment: Why would you use a GridView for presenting a List of strings?

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders, I'm a noob. I come from a database background. The JSON returned is a set of directions. I want to display each step as a row in the grid.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426454/liststring-as-gridview-datasource-what-do-i-put-for-datafield-in-the-gvs-bou

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways of listing those directions:

**1 - Using GridView:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdExample" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Directions">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Container.DataItem %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Binding the GridView:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "Ha!", "Hey!", "Yo!" };

grdExample.DataSource = strings;
grdExample.DataBind();
```

**2 - Using a Repeater (simpler and more flexible, requires your own HTML):**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptExample" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Container.DataItem %>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Binding it:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "Ha!", "Hey!", "Yo!" };

rptExample.DataSource = strings;
rptExample.DataBind();
```